# Unexpected audio signal interference with camera recording

Tags: audio, interference, ripple

When watching [this video](https://youtu.be/ldv3uh9kLPM?t=398) I noticed that low audio frequency creates a visual ripple effect. I'd like to know how this is possible. I guess this can't be due to software smoothing of whole-camera shaking, because video stabilizing algotihms produce different effects.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the low frequency is inducing vibrations in the camera. Video stabilization software is unlikely to react fast enough to remove them. Do an experiment - put a video camera on a bass speaker and hit it with some low frequency notes eg 30-50Hz and see what happens.

Comment: So the light sensitive part of the camera "changes shape", producing this effect? I will try out your idea, thanks.

Comment: Nothing interesting happened, perhaps of software processing and capture speed (fps). I tried on cellphone camera.